# Retrieving data with firebase returns nothing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load some data from firebase to use in my ios app, but it seems like the whole observe method doesn't get executed.

This is the data on firebase:

```
{
  "tips" : {
    "Nog een" : {
      "category" : "Drinking",
      "description" : "Dikke test jooo",
      "name" : "Nog een",
      "score" : 0
    },
    "testtip" : {
      "category" : "Going Out",
      "description" : "reteketet keta pret",
      "name" : "testtip",
      "score" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code for loading:

```
let tipsRef = Database.database().reference().child("tips")
        var tips: [Tip] = []
        tipsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if !snapshot.exists(){
                print("not found")
            }
            else{
                for item in snapshot.children{
                    let tip = Tip(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
                    tips.append(tip)
                }
                self.tipsArray = tips
            }
        })
```

The line if `!snapshot.exists(){` doesn't get reached.

In the same class i'm inserting these objects into the database and this goes without any problem.

```
let tipRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "tips")
let newTipRef = tipRef.child(newTip.name)
newTipRef.setValue(newTip.toAnyObject())
```

I have no idea why this is not working, in a similar project almost the same code DOES work...

UPDATE
Nirav D's answered helped me fix it, but now I need a new init for "Tip", I am not sure how to do this. I added the init i was using.

```
let tipsRef = Database.database().reference().child("tips")
        var tips: [Tip] = []
        tipsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] {
                for item in dictionary {
                    let tip = Tip(dictionary: item)
                    tips.append(tip)
                }
            }
            self.tipsArray = tips
        })



convenience init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
         self.init()
         let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
         self.name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
         self.description = snapshotValue["description"] as! String
         self.category = snapshotValue["category"] as! String
         self.score = snapshotValue["score"] as! Int
    }
```

Comment: You mean it is executing else block right?

Comment: It isn't, i updated my post, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure of `observe` will called async means it will called latter when you get response. Also may be you need to access `snapshot.value` instead of `snapshot.children`. If you are showing this data in tableView then you need to reload the `tableView` after the for loop.

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] {
    for item in dictionary {
        let tip = Tip(dictionary: item.value)
        tips.append(tip)
    }
    //Reload your table here
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Make one `init` like below in your `Tip` class.

```
init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as! String
    self.description = dictionary["description"] as! String
    self.category = dictionary["category"] as! String
    self.score = dictionary["score"] as! Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked! although I can't use my DataSnapshot init now... trying to make a constructor with [String:[String:Any]], but since i'm garbage at swift I can't seem to find how to do this...

Comment: @Sanderoo No you need init with `[String:Any]` edit your question with your old init I will suggest you how to write new init

Comment: @Sanderoo Welcome mate :)